# How do I crop out Region of Interest (ROI) from .mp4 video using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

I would like to crop out ROI from specific .mp4 file. User needs to define the ROI by specifying `X,Y,Width` and `Height` in percentage between 0 and 10000.

For example, if someone specifies `X=4000`, and `Y=3000` that would mean that top left corner (starting point of the crop) is located 40% to the right from bottom left corner of the video, and 30% down from top left corner of the video. `Width` and `Height` should determine bottom right and top left corners.

I am currently doing some tests on this image:

[image]

I expected following command to crop out 50% of the width and 50% of the height of the image, starting from top left corner:

```
ffmpeg -i test.png -filter:v "crop=in_w*(5000/10000):in_h*(5000/10000):in_w:in_h" -c:a copy roi.png
```

For some reason I get bottom right quarter instead of top left quarter of the image. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**EDIT**

Once I change command to:

```
 ffmpeg -i test.png -filter:v "crop=in_w*(5000/10000):in_h*(5000/10000):0:in_h" -c:a copy roi.png
```

I get top right quarter of the image:

[image]

Since I specified `X=in_w`, and `Y=0`, this means that `(X,Y)` is top-right corner of the image. If that is true, and `W` is 50% of `in_w`, while `H` is also 50% of `in_h`, and I specified `(X,Y)` to be at top right corner, how did **FFMPEG** decide that it needs to go to the **LEFT** of the `(X,Y)` coordinate and not to the **RIGHT** in order to make the crop?

Because if it went to the right like it normally does, it would go out of range I guess. How is this logic implemented? I would like to know so I know how to program edge cases for it.

Comment: The 4 parameter for `crop` are: `w:h:x:y`. You are providing width and height values for `x` and `y` - try `0:0` for `x:y`.

Comment: Also, all video filters measure x & y from top-left corner.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Thank you for your comments. Would you please look at the edit version of the issue.

Comment: @Gyan I would appreciate if you take a look as well.

Answer (score 2):

The crop filter arguments specify a crop window of the given width and height whose top-left corner is at co-ordinates (x, y) measured from top-left corner of the input frame. The entire crop window must be contained within the frame. So, to start with, `w <= iw && h <= ih`.

Then, `x+w <= iw && x >= 0` and `y+h <= ih && y >= 0`. If this condition isn't meant, x or y will be adjusted to auto-center the crop window along that axis, e.g. for a 100x100 input, if w = 50 and x = 60, then x is adjusted to (100-50)/2 = 25.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is info I've needed :)

Comment: @OzanÇakıroğlu, if it is what you needed, why not accept this answer (clicking on the check mark near it)?

Comment: @MarianD He already did, then unmarked it a few days later. He also changed his user name here to a different identity and deleted a couple of other Qs which I had answered.

Comment: @Gyan - it's very, very unseemly behavior, incomprehensible for me. But maybe he has some important reasons to do such things, hidden from others.